# Ansible is trying to apply condition on nested element I don't want

Tags: ansible

Given an item in `vars/all.yml`

```
websites:
    -
        dest: test_project
        db_password: 'xxxx'
        delete: false
```

And a `main.yml` that calls backend.yml on one condition

```
- debug: msg={{ websites | selectattr("dest", "equalto", project_name) | list }}
  register: website

ok: [xxx.com] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": [
        {
            "db_password": "xxxx", 
            "delete": false, 
            "dest": "test_project", 

        }
    ]
}

- include: backend.yml
  when: not website.msg.delete|bool
  #static: no #tried this too, but has no effect
```

Then, `backend.yml` containing :

```
...
- name: Grant ACL for write inside "wp-content" (default)
  acl:
    name: "{{ ansible_www_home }}/{{ item[0].dest }}/wp-content/"
    entity: "{{ item[1] }}"
    etype: group
    permissions: rwx
    state: present
  with_nested:
    - "{{ website.msg }}"
    - ['www-data', 'test']
...
```

Error is

```
The conditional check 'not item.delete|bool' failed. 
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not item.delete|bool): 'list object' has no attribute 'delete'

The error appears to have been in 'backend.yml': line 58, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem
```

It seems like Ansible is trying to look for `delete` property on the second nested array `['www-data', 'test']` which of course doesn't exist.

I don't understand why ansible is trying to apply my include condition on this level. I just want ansible to include the file if item.delete is not true and not try to call this condition on which step of `backend.yml`

Do you have an idea on how to fix it ?

PS: I tried to add `static: no` to the condition on `main.yml` but it's has no effect.

Comment: What did you want to do when you wrote `when: not item.delete|bool`?

Comment: I wanted to not include `backend.yml` (which install the project). Just skip the inclusion of this file.

Comment: What is `item`? Where is the loop defined?

Comment: Well, your question helped me narrow some irregularities: I updated to provide you the ouput of the debug. And Maybe I should do `when: not website.msg.delete|bool` but ansible still complaining about failed conditionnal check on task !

Comment: Well, if you don't know what `item` is, then probably you did not want to use `item`.

Comment: Yeah, seems pretty dumb, but I wrote this years ago. Anyway, thanks, thanks to you I figured that `when: not website.msg.0.delete|bool` is the solution to my answer with `static: no` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, figured that multiple stupid mistakes were made, solution is :

```
- include: backend.yml
  when: not website.msg.0.delete|bool
  static: no
```